# Adding DWM Thumbnails as WPF Control child

Tags: c#, wpf, thumbnails, dwm

I use DWM thumbnails to create a window picker and I want to add those thumbnails as children for a WPF `StackPanel`. How can I do that?

In this code, I have a `Grid` called `b` which I want to add the app thumbnail as a child of it.

### Code

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
private static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS pMargins);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MARGINS
{
    public int Left;
    public int Right;
    public int Top;
    public int Bottom;

    public void ExtendToWholeClientArea()
    {
        this.Left = -1;
        this.Right = -1;
        this.Top = -1;
        this.Bottom = -1;
    }
}

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmRegisterThumbnail(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, out IntPtr thumb);

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmUnregisterThumbnail(IntPtr thumb);

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmQueryThumbnailSourceSize(IntPtr thumb, out PSIZE size);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct PSIZE
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties(IntPtr hThumb, ref DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES props);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES
{
    public int dwFlags;
    public RECT rcDestination;
    public RECT rcSource;
    public byte opacity;
    public bool fVisible;
    public bool fSourceClientAreaOnly;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct RECT
{
    public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        Right = right;
        Bottom = bottom;
    }

    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}

private static readonly int DWM_TNP_VISIBLE = 0x8;
private static readonly int DWM_TNP_RECTDESTINATION = 0x1;
private static readonly int DWM_TNP_SOURCECLIENTAREAONLY = 0x00000010;
```

```
private void DrawThumbnail(WindowInfo win, int thumbnailIndex)
{ 
    IntPtr thumbnail = win.Thumbnail;

    if (thumbnail != IntPtr.Zero)
        DwmUnregisterThumbnail(thumbnail);

    int hResult = DwmRegisterThumbnail(mainWindowHandle, win.HWnd, out thumbnail);

    if (hResult == 0)
    {
        PSIZE size;
        DwmQueryThumbnailSourceSize(thumbnail, out size);

        DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES props = new DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES();
        props.dwFlags = DWM_TNP_VISIBLE | DWM_TNP_RECTDESTINATION | DWM_TNP_SOURCECLIENTAREAONLY;
        props.fVisible = true;
        props.fSourceClientAreaOnly = true;
        
        Grid b = new Grid() 
        { 
             Height = ThumbnailSize + 20, 
             Width = ThumbnailSize + WindowLeftOffset, 
             Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#55D3E6EE")), 
             Tag = UnSelectedTag,
             VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
             HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
        };
        b.MouseLeftButtonDown += B_MouseLeftButtonDown;

        //Set the region where the live preview will be drawn ======> I want to add this region as a child for "b" grid 
        int left = (thumbnailIndex % MaxThumbnails) * (ThumbnailSize + ThumbnailSpacing)+ WindowLeftOffset;
        int top = (int)(thumbnailIndex / MaxThumbnails) * (ThumbnailSize + ThumbnailSpacing) + WindowTopOffset;
        int right = left + ThumbnailSize;
        int bottom = top + ThumbnailSize;

        props.rcDestination = new RECT(left, top, right, bottom);

        var bor = new Border() 
        { 
             BorderThickness = new Thickness(1), 
             BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#550863A2")), 
             CornerRadius= new CornerRadius(2) 
        };
        bor.Child = b;
        bor.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)(((drowingIndex % MaxThumbnails) * (ThumbnailSize + ThumbnailSpacing))+WindowLeftOffset - (WindowLeftOffset/2)-1));
        bor.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Math.Floor((double)(drowingIndex / MaxThumbnails)) * (ThumbnailSize + ThumbnailSpacing));
        canvas.Children.Add(bor);

        drowingIndex++;
        previweStackPanels.Add(b);

        //Center the live preview
        if (size.x < size.y)
        {
            double ScaleFactor = ThumbnailSize / (double)size.y;
            int scaledX = (int)(size.x * ScaleFactor);
            int xOffset = (ThumbnailSize - scaledX) / 2;
            props.rcDestination.Left += xOffset;
            props.rcDestination.Right -= xOffset;
        }

        if (size.y < size.x)
        {
            double ScaleFactor = ThumbnailSize / (double)size.x;
            int scaledY = (int)(size.y * ScaleFactor);
            int yOffset = (ThumbnailSize - scaledY) / 2;
            props.rcDestination.Top += yOffset;
            props.rcDestination.Bottom -= yOffset;
        }

        DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties(thumbnail, ref props);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Panel` such as a `Grid` and a `StackPanel` has a `Children` collection to which you can add `UIElement`s:

```
previweStackPanels.Children.Add(b);
```

Note that you cannot add anything else but `UIElement` objects to a `Panel` though.

This means that you *cannot* add a `RECT` to the `Grid` because a `RECT` is not a `UIElement`. You could add a `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` though:

Comment: no I want to add this Rectangle `props.rcDestination = new RECT(left, top, right, bottom);` as a child .. previweStackPanels is just a list of all StackPanels

Comment: As a child of what?

Comment: of `b` Grid .. so I have Thumbnail for running window and I want to add this Thumbnail of this window as a child or content of Grid `b`

Comment: I guess you should read my answer again. You can *only* add UIElements to a Grid's Children collection and since a RECT is not a UI element you *cannot* add this one to the Grid. You could add a System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle though.